# multiple definition of 'true' - but its not?

Tags: c

I have a double type bool so have added to a header:

```
typedef double bool;
extern bool true;
extern bool false;
```

with:

```
bool true = 1.0;
bool false = 0.0;
```

in the corresponding C file.

However I now have  the errors multiple definition of true, and the same for false, pointing to the first line of the first function in the C file. the error that says 'previous declaration was here' points to the same line... it doesnt make any difference which function is placed first in the file it always points to it.

My header files, though included via a common header file, do have include guards so I hopefully *shouldn't* have multiple declaration of true and false there.

I have changed the typedef to tBool with vars tTrue and tFalse, which solves the problem, but I don't get why it occurred in the first place? As there are still some bool types using true and false in the code it seems like the compiler may have a definition for true and false as ints already... though I didn't think C did this

Im using dev-c++ 4.9.9.2 IDE that uses mingw, though Im not sure which version mingw.

Anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Just tried this in  an eclipse based IDE that uses a different compiler with no problem, so I guess its mingw.

Comment: Are you (explicitly or otherwise, perhaps through an IDE-generated precompiled header) including stdbool.h? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html

Comment: Even if the identifiers `bool`, `true` and `false` were not already reserved by `stdbool.h` for the purpose that you can easily imagine, declaring them with a base type of `double` is the weirdest attempt to emulate a Boolean type that I have ever seen. Just don't do cruft like that.

Comment: @Graham Maybe. I have stdlib, string and stdio included, but just tried commenting each and all out with no change. In fact commenting them all out doesn't produce any additional errors and the program still works so I guess these are being added by the compiler  which prob means stdbool is being added similarly...ta

Comment: @Jens, yeah I guess it is, and I've tried to avoid it but in this case bool is a type of parameter where the parameter may also be a double number. I may have lots of parameters for so I dont want to have to create different typed arrays for each type of possible parameter and then have to keep track of indexes of each array to correlate the parameters to their other relevant info. this is ugly but better in my opinion.

Comment: You are not by any chance compiling this as `C++` code?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't include your *.c file (this would be a very bad idea) ?

Comment: @Toby, I don't get a word of your explanation. In any case, don't name your stuff such that everybody would suspect it to be a Boolean type, when it isn't.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++? In C++ those words are already reserved, and in C they can be defined in the header `<stdbool.h>`. Also, by use `double` as the boolean type? Normally it's either `char` or `int` or an enumeration.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg pretty sure Im compiling as C. all files are named .c
build commands are like: $(CC) -c SCPI_Parser.c -o SCPI_Parser.o $(CFLAGS)
so guessing it is def C compiled

Comment: @Toby - *may have lots of parameters for so I dont want to have to create different typed arrays for each type of possible parameter and then have to keep track of indexes of each array to correlate the parameters to their other relevant info* - That would indeed be very bad.  However, this is probably worse.  If you need to pass a lot of parameters into a function, you should use a `struct`!  This will allow you to create named 'indexes' into the parameter.  Alternatively, you should think about completely refactoring your code; it sounds like you've got a lot of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like your parameter is not really a [Boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) value at all.  You have a floating point parameter with special cases for the discrete numbers 0.0 and 1.0.  Create two `double` constants instead of a type.

C99 added definitions for the type `_Bool`, a **macro** `bool`, a **macro** `true`, and a **macro** `false`.  Try inserting the following in your header:

```
#if __bool_true_false_are_defined
# error "stdbool.h has been included"
#endif
#ifdef bool
# error "bool is already DEFINED"
#endif
#ifdef true
# error "true is already DEFINED"
#endif
#ifdef false
# error "false is already DEFINED"
#endif
```

If any of these fire, then you are including *stdbool.h* somewhere.  You should be able to `#undef` the three macros and then set up your types safely.  Of course, this will probably break if someone else expects `bool` to be a small integer value and has more style problems that you can shake a stick at.

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 does make a concession to the fact that many groups have already defined their own Boolean types before it was added to the Standard.  This is the rationale for defining `bool`, `true`, and `false` as macros instead of new keywords.  However, the following warning is explicitly included:

> **7.26.7 Boolean types and values `<stdbool.h>`**
>
> The ability to undefine and then perhaps redefine the macros **`bool`**, **`true`**, and **`false`** is an obsolescent feature.